# Find out if Java program is running from CMD or not

Tags: java, cmd

I want to write a Java program that receives input through text (a console program).
When this program starts up, straight away in the *main* method, I want to be able to check if the program was started from a Command Prompt (cmd) or from a JAR file. This is so that I can open a JFrame to receive input if there is no cmd to receive it.

Essentially, something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    if(startedFromCmd()) {
        startProgram();
    } else{
        openInputFrame();
        startProgram();
    }
}
```

Is there any built-in Java method which can check this?

Comment: What if it was started crom the CMD using a jar file?

Comment: actually you could simply check if your program has received input or not using the length of command line arguements. Thus, if input has been received, you can simple execute the input command. IF inpout has not been received, open a Frame to receive the input from the user.

Comment: A Java program can be started from a command prompt *and* a JAR file at the same time. Nothing to stop you opening a `JFrame` either way.  Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Well, yes, you can start a JAR file from a cmd, but in that case it runs in the cmd doesn't it? Let's put it like this; if I use System.out.println("...") where does that text go? If it shows up in a cmd then I don't have to open a JFrame since I can write input into that cmd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System.console()` which returns a console object if there is one attached to the Java Virtual Machine.

The method returns `null` if there is no console attached. Note that this is not 100% reliable. E.g. the method returns `null` for the internal console in the Eclipse IDE (which is actually bug [#122429](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429)). It works with the Windows command line though.

An example could look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    if (System.console() != null)
    {
        System.out.println("There is a console!");
    }
    else
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("There is no console!");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Running this in the Windows command line with `java -jar MyJar.jar` will result in

`There is a console!`

being printed on the console.

Double clicking the .jar-file will show a `JFrame`.

Comment: Perfect!! This is exactly what I was looking for =)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the CMD process that are running currently by using WMIC command. However, this works on windows only. For unix/Mac you can use something similar to ps -ef|grep java.
wmic process where "name like '%java%'" get commandline,processid

Above command will fetch you the list of java process in which you can filter out your file. Please find a sample code [here](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-theory-questions/6289-using-java-access-system-resources.html)